Longtable not running over pages in landscape
My problem is that when I do have text in the table as it is set up here the long table does not run over the page in landscape orientation. Any help?
 \documentclass[12pt, a4paper,margin=0.5in]{article}

% Packages needed for the table
\usepackage{tabularx} % For flexible table widths
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage[paper=portrait,pagesize]{typearea}


\begin{document}

\begin{center}
\KOMAoptions{paper=landscape,pagesize}
\recalctypearea
% Define the width of the table to fit the page and column types
\begin{longtable}{|p{0.01\textwidth}|p{0.1\textwidth}|p{0.4\textwidth}|p{0.4\textwidth}|p{0.4\textwidth}|}
\hline
\textbf{} & \textbf{Name} & \textbf{Why} & \textbf{How} & \textbf{My Role}\\
\hline
1 & name&\lipsum[1-4]& \lipsum[1-4]&  \lipsum[1-4] \\
\hline
18 & name &  \lipsum[1-4]& T \lipsum[1-4] &  \lipsum[1-4]\\
\hline

\end{longtable}
\end{center}

\newpage

\KOMAoptions{paper=portrait,pagesize}
\recalctypearea

\lipsum[1-4]

\end{document}


It can't break pages in the middle of cells. So if you have cells which are taller than the current height of the text block, they will just overflow for want of anywhere better to go. You need to structure the table so that it is possible for longtable to find places to break in between the rows. As it is, it does insert breaks when it can. It just isn't sufficient.
